# Can not get i18n value after changeLanguage

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have try to code an endpoint in express and here is my file structure:

```
.
├── API/
│   └── login.js
└── i18n/
    └── index.js
```

**login.js** (I tried to use i18n.t() and i18n.getResource()

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import MetaTags from "react-meta-tags"
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

export default function Login(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const history = useHistory()
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation("ActivateActivate")

  const changeLanguageHandler = (lang) => { 
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang) 
    console.log(i18n.language, i18n.t("Login Now"), "i18n.t")
    console.log(i18n.language, i18n.getResource(i18n.language, "ActivateActivate", "Login Now"), "i18n.getResource")
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    changeLanguageHandler("zh-hk") 

    changeLanguageHandler("en")

    changeLanguageHandler("zh-hk") 
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

i18n/index.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

let resources = {
  "en": {
    "ActivateActivate": {
      "Login Now": "Login Now現在登入"
    },
  },
  "zh-hk": {
    "ActivateActivate": {
      "Login Now": "現在登入"
    },
  },
}

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    preload: ['en', 'zh-hk', 'zh-cn'],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: true,

    // have a common namespace used around the full app
    ns: ["ActivateActivate"],
    // defaultNS: "ActivateActivate",
    
    keySeparator: false, // we use content as keys
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

Here is the result:

```
i18next: languageChanged zh-hk
i18next.js:31 i18next::translator: missingKey zh-hk translation Login Now Login Now
Login.js:125 zh-hk Login Now i18n.t
Login.js:126 zh-hk 現在登入 i18n.getResource
i18next.js:31 i18next: languageChanged en
i18next.js:31 i18next::translator: missingKey en translation Login Now Login Now
Login.js:125 en Login Now i18n.t
Login.js:126 en Login Now現在登入 i18n.getResource
i18next.js:31 i18next: languageChanged zh-hk
i18next.js:31 i18next::translator: missingKey zh-hk translation Login Now Login Now
Login.js:125 zh-hk Login Now i18n.t
Login.js:126 zh-hk 現在登入 i18n.getResource
```

For the result, i18n.getResource() selecting correct language, but i18n.t() mapping wrong value, my question is:

1. Why showing "translator: missingKey en translation" in error log?
2. What is the reason that i18n.t() mapping wrong value?

How can I fix? Thanks all!

======================================

**[Update]**
I found that `i18n.t()` is not work in my codes reason:

1. `i18n.t()` using default namespace "translator" which is not my selecting namespace
2. `i18n.t()` can not switch language after using `i18n.changeLanguage()`

Is that helpful for solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the namespace level in the resources:

```
let resources = {
  "en": {
   "translation": {
    "ActivateActivate": {
      "Login Now": "Login Now現在登入"
    }
   }
  },
  "zh-hk": {
   "translation": {
    "ActivateActivate": {
      "Login Now": "現在登入"
    }
   }
  }
}
```

and you also need to use the correct key path in the t call:

```
i18n.t("ActivateActivate.Login Now")
```

Comment: i18n.t() still cannot return a collect value of "Login Now"

Comment: the key path is probably also wrong: i18n.t("ActivateActivate.Login Now")

Comment: showing `en` language "Login Now現在登入" if using `i18n.t("ActivateActivate.Login Now")` and cannot switch to other language. I tried to using `i18n.changeLanguage()` but nothing result changed..